# Python Try Except with Simple Numerical Conditions

Tags: python, numeric, try-except

This python code lets a user enter in a numeric grade from which a letter output is given, but it also tries to take into account string user-inputs, or numeric user-inputs that are outside the range of 0.0 to 1.0, by delivering an error message as an output.

```
score = input("Enter Score: ")

try:
    sr = float(score)
    sr <= 1.0
    sr >= 0.0
except:
    print("Number entered must be between 0.0 and 1.0")
    quit()

if sr >=0.9:
    print ("A")
elif sr >=0.8:
    print ("B")
elif sr >=0.7:
    print ("C")
elif sr >=0.6:
    print ("D")
else:
    print ("F")
```

The issue I have is that when the user input is 1.2, I expect to get the error output I specified, "Number entered must be between 0.0 and 1.0". But instead I get an output of "A".

I understand that instead of using a 'try except' structure, I could use if statements to get the desired error message, but I just want to understand why the try-except code doesn't work the way I want it to.

Thanks bunches :).

P.S. First time posting, so apologies if I'm messing up with regards to stack overflow question etiquette or what have you.

Comment: try/except statements are used for catching exceptions. You should use `if` and `else` for checking whether a number is in a certain range.

Comment: `sr <= 1.0` returns a boolean, it does not raise an exception. What you can do however, using this current structure, is to use `assert sr <= 1.0`, this will raise AssertionError when it returns non truthy value—which can be caught by your `except` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are expecting...

```
score = input("Enter Score: ")

try:
    sr = float(score)
    assert sr <= 1.0    #needs an assert keyword
    assert sr >= 0.0    #needs an assert keyword
except:
    print("Number entered must be between 0.0 and 1.0")
    quit()
```

If you don't write assert the `sr <= 1.0`, it simply tries to compute the value and discard it as you are not assigning it to anything.

Alternatively you can use an if statement and quit in the if the condition doesn't match like this.

```
score = input("Enter Score: ")

sr = float(score)

if sr > 1.0 or sr < 0.0:    
    print("Number entered must be between 0.0 and 1.0")
    quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

The lines:

```
sr <= 1.0
sr >= 0.0
```

compute two booleans and then don't use the values. What I think you want is:

```
try:
    sr = float(score)
    assert(sr <= 1.0)
    assert(sr >= 0.0)
except:
    print("Number entered must be between 0.0 and 1.0")
    quit()
```

Assert raises an AssertionError when the value of the parameter is false.